# How to block asnchronous call in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have following piece of code:

```
if (!project) {
        let pk_map =  this.backend.get_pk_map ()
        let pk = false
        if (pk_map.hasOwnProperty (path)) {
          pk =  pk_map[path]
        }
        const _this  = this
        if (!pk) {
          _this.network.getPackages (false , function (data){ 
              //here i want to block as I need pk for next call
              //  I cant do project =  this.network.getProject(data.pk) here
              // as I have further code too
               pk =  data.pk
           })
        }

        project =  this.network.getProject(pk) // Need the Pk here
 }
```

I want to block the async call at `_this.network.getPackages`. How can I do this?

Comment: What is getPackages? It has no completion event/callback? Add one?

Comment: You can't  the very purpose of async model is being non blocking lol.
Use js promices to listen for both network events being executed.

Comment: it have callback where I am receiving data , as you can see third argument

Comment: You will have to write your dependent code in the callback.